# Oracle SQL in and not in both return empty

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a people table that contains a username column.
I also have a student table that contains a username column.
"David" exist in people table, but not in  student table.

When I run this, I get no result which is not right:

```
Select      USERNAME
From        PEOPLE
Where       username = 'david' and USERNAME not in (Select USERNAME From STUDENT) 
Order By    USERNAME
```

However, when I run this, I also get no result. How is this possible?

```
Select      USERNAME
From        PEOPLE
Where       username = 'david' and USERNAME in (Select USERNAME From STUDENT) 
Order By    USERNAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any `USERNAME` in `student` is `NULL`, then the expression evaluates to `NULL`.  That filters out *all* rows.  I am guessing that is your problem.

To fix this problem, I recommend *never* using `NOT IN` with a subquery.  Simply get used to using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
where username = 'david' and
      not exists (select 1 from student s where s.USERNAME = people.username)
```

Comment: "Never use NOT IN" is bad advice (because of "never"). To deal with NULL, one approach is to use NOT EXISTS. Another, equally valid approach is to say "NOT IN (select USERNAME from STUDENT **WHERE USERNAME IS NOT NULL**)". Just because you prefer NOT EXISTS doesn't mean one should "never" use NOT IN. Just use it correctly.